# Is there any sort order that can be passed to query which will tell solr to sort results in same order like in query

Tags: sorting, solr

I am making a Solr request and passing id of the docs in fq parameter . Solr as expected returns the doc sorted by score of the docs . I want Solr to return docs in the same order as i sent the ids .

So is there a value to sort parameter than i can give to get the desired result .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible in solr to specify an ordering of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813548/is-it-possible-in-solr-to-specify-an-ordering-of-documents)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing to fq. Use elevator component.

Edit elevate.xml file in your solr conf folder and

```
<query text="ipod">
   <doc id="S03" /> 
   <doc id="S01" />  
   <doc id="S02" /> 
 </query>
```

irrespective of solr score value, it returns docs in order how you given in elevate.xml file.

OR

Use bq (Boosting) parameter with edismax.
example:

```
defType=edismax&q="ipod"&bq=id:S03^4+id:S02^3+id:S01^
```

Comment: sample query : `localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/elevate?q=ipod`

Comment: can't edit the elevate.xml file . Not an option . Need to do it through the code only

Comment: I edited my answer. try that way. change boost values according to you.

Comment: You can also change operator between id's. AND, OR

Answer (score 0):

The default sort order - if no sort is provided and all scores are similar (or using just `fq`'s - should be the internal Lucene ID - meaning you should get the documents back in the order they're added.

You can ask for this explicitly by using `sort=_docid_ asc`.

But if this is really important - as documents will get reordered if updated and you might want to keep the original sorting order, add a field to keep track of the time when the document was added and sort by that field.

Comment: That is useful info but the ask is to preserve the order of ids specified in `fq` regardless of when the documents were added/updated.

Comment: That depends on your interpretation of "same order as I sent the ids". If you want them ordered by the order in the query, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807256/how-to-get-solr-results-in-given-order-specified-in-query/25816214#25816214