# Sort by multiple fields in specific order in Solr

Tags: sorting, solr, solr-query-syntax

So I want to sort my Solr response by the following fields:

- published_year (desc)
- series_number (asc)
- status_color

Problem is that `status_color` must be sorted by the following values (e.i. not alphabetically):

- "Green"
- "Yellow"
- "Red"

This field may only contain one of these values.

I'm hoping theres a way of doing this in the Solr query instead of massaging the result in code. With a result of hundreds of thounsands of documents it's not really an option.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer for this question will be valid for you too:

[Is it possible in solr to specify an ordering of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813548/is-it-possible-in-solr-to-specify-an-ordering-of-documents)

Answer (score 3):

I believe Solr has [Enum types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Enum+Fields), though I have never seen them used in a while. But they would be a perfect match, so worth a try.

Comment: This is very interesting. Are enum values sorted by their position in the config?